# Is there a way to search/sort questions by more complex conditions?

Tags: support

I'm looking to burn some reputation off via bounties, so I'd like to be able to look for questions with unaccepted but high-voted (>= 2) answers to throw those who answered a bone, or high-voted old questions with only low-voted answers to try to attract more.

Are either of these views possible?

Comment: Here is a simple modification I made to it to get questions with no accepted answers. http://data.stackexchange.com/gamedev/q/77290/unaccepted-but-high-voted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use the SE Data Explorer to do this. You can access it from http://data.stackexchange.com

Also, this query my be helpful for getting to what you are looking for.
http://data.stackexchange.com/gamedev/s/403/unpopular-questions-with-great-answers

Comment: I had no idea this existed and it's pretty nifty.